# Can I safely reinstall PCManFM in Lubuntu desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, openbox, pcmanfm

I seem to have some problems with pcmanfm (openbox took over my desktop) and I would like to reinstall in Synaptic but it says it wants to remove (reinstall eventually) `lubuntu-core`, `lubuntu-default` settings and `lubuntu-desktop`. Is that safe?

After installing `lxde` and `lxde-core`, uninstalling `pcmanfm` involves removing them too.

Comment: Edit your question to include the packages it wants to remove. Is it `lubuntu-desktop` only which is going to remove?

Comment: Hello cipricus. Might I ask what the conflict you are experiencing is? You say Openbox has taken over the desktop,  what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said you want to remove and eventually reinstall (if I correctly understand your question) I would say, it is okay to do so.

Also note, `lubuntu-desktop`, `lubuntu-core` are metapackge which actually doesn't install anything *(those packages are used to pull other packages)* and `lubuntu-default-settings` is used to set the default settings of Lubuntu, such as default background, theme, icon-theme, keyboard shortcuts and others.

You said, when you wanted to remove `pcmanfm`, synaptic said, it will also remove `lubuntu-desktop`, `lubuntu-core`, `lubuntu-default-settings`, `lxde` and `lxde-core`. This is normal since package `pcmanfm` is a dependency (you may say required package) for those packages and when you tried to remove it, there is no reason to keep those packages. (Because those packages wouldn't install without pcmanfm).

If you really wanted to reinstall pcmanfm and you have another DE such as Xfce or KDE or Unity (GNOME), I recommend you to switch to that DE and run this command in a terminal to remove and reinstall the packages.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove pcmanfm
```

This will remove pcmanfm, those other five packages with all of their configuration files. Now use this command to reinstall everything

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop lubuntu-default-settings lxde
```

Note that this command did not explicitly say to install `pcmanfm` but that package will be installed as a dependency package of `lubuntu-core` which will itself be installed as a dependency of `lubuntu-desktop`.

If you don't have other DE installed, just switch to one of the virtual console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and execute the commands.  To return to the graphical session, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>  .

This should help you to reinstall pcmanfm.